# Use Rodrigues' formula to derive the following property for legendre polynomial

Tags: real-analysis

The Rodrigues' formula says: $\phi_{0}(x)=1$, $\phi_n(x)=\frac{((x^2-1)^n)^{(n)}}{2^nn!}$ $\forall n\geq 1 $

where $\phi_n$ is the $n^{th}$
Legendre Polynomial

and I have already derived:  $\phi'_n(x)=x\phi'_{n-1}(x)+n\phi_{n-1}(x)$

How do I show:
$$\phi_n(x)=x\phi_{n-1}(x)+\frac{x^2-1}{n}\phi'_{n-1}(x)$$

Answer (score 1):

See my other post dated yesterday: [[Differentiate $((x^{2}-1)f_{n-1}(x))^{(n)}$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3576782/differentiate-x2-1f-n-1xn/3581978#3581978) ]

Note that there I used two other well-known properties of Legendre polynomials:

\begin{equation}
(n+1)P_{n+1} = (2n+1)xP_n-nP_{n-1}
\end{equation}
and
\begin{equation}
P_{n+1}'-P_{n-1}' = (2n+1)P_n
\end{equation}

Also note that the derived formula is slightly different than what you mentioned:

$$\frac{x^2-1}{n}P_n' = xP_n - P_{n-1}$$
But you can easily derive the formula you are looking for as follows:
$$(x^2-1)P_n' = nxP_n - nP_{n-1} = (n+1)P_{n+1} - (n+1)xP_n$$
hence
$$\frac{x^2-1}{n+1}P_{n}' = P_{n+1} - xP_n$$
replacing $n$ by $n-1$ then gives:
$$\frac{x^2-1}{n}P_{n-1}' = P_{n} - xP_{n-1}$$
As required.